# Changes to mass_assignment_authorizer cause errors in Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

Protecting against mass assignment as in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible) no longer works in Rails 3.1.

Error given is:

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

for

```
app/models/user.rb:20:in `mass_assignment_authorizer'
```

Comment: Giving mass_assignment_authorizer a dummy parameter gets this working again, far from ideal though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to implement the override technique in [Ryan's Railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible), but using Rails 3.1.0, then re-writing the private def in the model to:

```
def mass_assignment_authorizer(role = :default)
 super + (accessible || [])
end
```

I found this cleared the

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

error above (ie just adding (role = :default), and also correlates with the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the source it appears that, at least in master, there is a default option of :default for mass_assignment_authorizer as seen [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb#L231).

Which version of rails 3.1 are you using?, it may be worth trying it against head by changing your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git@github.com:rails/rails.git'
```

Comment: Currently using rc4, i'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Same problem with your suggestion, I don't think :default is getting defined.